# How to use "PUT" http method with Alamofire?

Tags: alamofire

We have a rest API which accepts parameters in URL. This API is using "PUT" http method. But Alamofire does not allow "PUT" for sending parameters in url.

To make it work I have to edit Alamofire code. I have to add .PUT as an extra case as follows.

```
        func encodesParametersInURL(method: Method) -> Bool {
            switch self {
            case .URLEncodedInURL:
                return true
            default:
                break
            }

            switch method {
            case .GET, .PUT, .HEAD, .DELETE:
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
        }
```

What will be the other solutions can anyone share please.

Thanks

Comment: If you’ve tested that edit and it is working for you, submit a pull request to Alamofire. They will either accept it or explain why they don’t support it.

Answer (score 1):

This is why we added the `.URLEncodedInURL` parameter encoding case. Instead of using the `.URL` encoding, switch to `.URLEncodedInURL` which will place the `.PUT` parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

From alamofire 4.0 onwards you can use , URLEncoding.queryString to place .PUT parameters in the URL.

`let urlRequest = try URLEncoding.queryString.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)`